# After upgrade, Debian can access internet, but not local network

Tags: networking, xen

I recently upgraded from Jessie to Stretch, and now, while I get an ip address from my router (which is also showing up properly as my default gateway, at least according to "ip r"), and I can access the internet, I can't reach any of my local network directly (tried ping, traceroute, and nslookup).

Local machine's IP address is 192.168.1.115

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
```

If I ping 192.168.1.1 from my other machine, I get a response, but from this one, I get:

```
From 192.168.1.115 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

w3m can access google.com, but not 192.168.1.1 (which is accessible through firefox from my other machine).

Comment: Guess: You need to enable something like "clients can talk to each other" on your router.

Comment: It seems your router does not include a route to your local network in the DHCP answers it gives, so that's where I would look, and the relevant setting might very well be called something like what @dirkt says.

Comment: @Henrik: The route to the local network on the router must be set, otherwise the client wouldn't get responses from the internet. However, many routers have a "feature" where you can allow/disallow clients to talk to each other (which is implemented with firewall rules).

Comment: You're right so far as there needs to be a route to the gateway fro the computer to get traffic to/from it (and through that, the rest of the internet). If the route is (properly) set, traffic to other devices on the local network shouldn't go to the router, but only the switch. As that is nowadays often build into the router, that could intercept the traffic from the "switch" part, and block that so you might be right, in which case another solution would be to inject a proper switch in the network, so traffic between devices doesn't have to go through the "router".

Comment: The machines on my local network could talk to each other without a problem before I upgraded this one's Debian version. Nothing on the router's been changed, just the Debian machine. Could it still be something with the router (or built-in switch in the router?).

Comment: Useful diagnostic information can be found by running `ip route list` - consider adding its output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

A restart without any further changes has resulted in everything working as it ought. As far as I know, the changes I had made either didn't require a restart of any services or were followed by my restarting the particular service that I changed, so I'm not sure what fixed it, unfortunately.